# How can I write a semaphore in Java which prioritizes previous successful applicants?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a need for a single-permit semaphore object in my Java program where there is an additional acquire method which looks like this:

```
boolean tryAcquire(int id)
```

and behaves as follows: if the id has not been encountered before, then remember it and then just do whatever `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` does.  If the id *has* been encountered before *and* that encounter resulted in the lease of the permit then give this thread priority over all other threads who may be waiting for the permit.  I'll also want an extra release method like:

```
void release(int id)
```

which does whatever the `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` does, plus also "forgets" about the id.

I don't really know how to approach this, but here's the start of a possible implementation but I fear it's going nowhere:

```
public final class SemaphoreWithMemory {

    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);
    private final Set<Integer> favoured = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer>();

    public boolean tryAcquire() {
        return semaphore.tryAcquire();
    }

    public synchronized boolean tryAcquire(int id) {
        if (!favoured.contains(id)) {
            boolean gotIt = tryAcquire();
            if (gotIt) {
                favoured.add(id);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            // what do I do here???
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        semaphore.release();
    }

    public synchronized void release(int id) {
        favoured.remove(id);
        semaphore.release();
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this best be solved with something like a concurrent priority queue?

Comment: It's not clear how `tryAcquire()` is related to "waiting threads" since it's non-blocking.

Comment: @Andrew yeah maybe, I don't know how one of those works.

Comment: The stated problem doesn't make  sense in its current form. tryAcquire is non blocking therefore if a thread has already acquired the lock, it has to fail independent of the given id and if no thread has acquired the lock the thread will succeed independent of the given id. This mechanism would only make sense in a blocking acquire method and there you just use a queue and insert the new thread either in the front or end depending on id.

Comment: @jujuma: should your new method be tryAcquire(int) or acquire(int)? It seems several of us are scratching our heads over how tryAcquire(int) might work.

Comment: What consensus problem are you actually trying to achieve? You have presented a problem of implementation of an answer, but not the original question. It is very hard to reverse-engineer the problem you are trying to solve with this structure. Additionally, a single-permit Semaphore is basically just a lock.

Comment: It just sounds like he wants a PriorityLock regardless of is error in using tryAcquire as an example

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
Did some experiment. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206318/how-can-i-write-a-semaphore-in-java-which-prioritizes-previous-successful-applica/5209461#5209461) for results.

In principle, Semaphore has a queue of threads internally, so like Andrew says if you make this queue a priority queue and poll from this queue to give out permits, it probably behaves the way you want. Note that you can't do this with `tryAcquire` because that way threads don't queue up. From what I see looks like you'd have to hack the [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java.html) class to do this.

I could also think of a probabilistic approach, like this:
(I'm not saying that the code below would be a good idea! Just brainstorming here. )

```
public class SemaphoreWithMemory {

    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    private final Set<Integer> favoured = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer>();
    private final ThreadLocal<Random> rng = //some good rng

    public boolean tryAcquire() {
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
            Thread.yield();
            // Tend to waste more time than tryAcquire(int id)
            // would waste.
            if(rng.get().nextDouble() < 0.3){
                return semaphore.tryAcquire();
            }
        }
        return semaphore.tryAcquire();
    }

    public boolean tryAcquire(int id) {
        if (!favoured.contains(id)) {
            boolean gotIt = semaphore.tryAcquire();
            if (gotIt) {
                favoured.add(id);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return tryAquire();
    }
}
```

Or have the "favoured" threads hang out a little bit longer like this:
**EDIT:** Turns out this was a very bad idea (with both fair and non-fair semaphore) (see my [experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206318/how-can-i-write-a-semaphore-in-java-which-prioritizes-previous-successful-applica/5209461#5209461) for details.

```
    public boolean tryAcquire(int id) {
        if (!favoured.contains(id)) {
            boolean gotIt = semaphore.tryAcquire(5,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (gotIt) {
                favoured.add(id);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return tryAquire();
    }
```

I guess this way you can bias the way permits are issued, while it won't be fair. Though with this code you'd probably be wasting a lot of time performance wise...

Answer (score 1):

For blocking acquisition model, what about this:

```
public class SemWithPreferred {
    int max;
    int avail;
    int preferredThreads;

    public SemWithPreferred(int max, int avail) {
        this.max = max;
        this.avail = avail;
    }

    synchronized public void get(int id) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean thisThreadIsPreferred = idHasBeenServedSuccessfullyBefore(id);
        if (thisThreadIsPreferred) {
            preferredThreads++;
        }
        while (! (avail > 0 && (preferredThreads == 0 || thisThreadIsPreferred))) {
            wait();
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("granted, id = %d, preferredThreads = %d", id, preferredThreads));
        avail -= 1;
        if (thisThreadIsPreferred) {
            preferredThreads--;
            notifyAll(); // removal of preferred thread could affect other threads' wait predicate
        }
    }

    synchronized public void put() {
        if (avail < max) {
            avail += 1;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    boolean idHasBeenServedSuccessfullyBefore(int id) {
        // stubbed out, this just treats any id that is a 
        // multiple of 5 as having been served successfully before 
        return id % 5 == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the threads to wait, I hacked a solution that is not perfect, but should do.

The idea is to have two semaphores and a "favourite is waiting" flag.

Every thread that tries to acquire the SemaphoreWithMemory first tries to acquire the "favouredSemaphore". A "favoured" thread keeps the Semaphore and a non-favoured releases it immediately. Thereby the favoured thread blocks all other incoming threads once he has acquired this Semaphore.

Then the second "normalSemaphore" has to be acquired to finish up.
But the non-favoured thread then checks again that there is no favoured thread waiting using a volatile variable). If none is waiting then he simply continues; if one is waiting, he releases the normalSemaphore and recursively calls acquire again.

I am not really sure that there are no race conditions lurking. If you want to be sure, you perhaps should refactor your code to hand of "work items" to a priority queue, where another thread takes the work item with the highest priority and executes that code.

```
public final class SemaphoreWithMemory {

private volatile boolean favouredAquired = false;
private final Semaphore favouredSemaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);
private final Semaphore normalSemaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);
private final Set<Integer> favoured = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer>();

public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
    normalSemaphore.acquire();
}

public void acquire(int id) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean idIsFavoured = favoured.contains(id);
    favouredSemaphore.acquire();
    if (!idIsFavoured) {
        favouredSemaphore.release();
    } else {
        favouredAquired = true;
    }
    normalSemaphore.acquire();

    // check again that there is no favoured thread waiting
    if (!idIsFavoured) {
        if (favouredAquired) {
            normalSemaphore.release();
            acquire(); // starving probability!
        } else {
            favoured.add(id);
        }
    }

}

public void release() {
    normalSemaphore.release();
    if (favouredAquired) {
        favouredAquired = false;
        favouredSemaphore.release();
    }
}

public void release(int id) {
    favoured.remove(id);
    release();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read this article by [Ceki](http://ceki.blogspot.com/2009/06/biased-locking-in-java-se-60.html) and was interested how biased semaphore acquisition could be (since I felt the "biased locking" behavior would make sense in semaphores as well..). On my hardware with 2 processors and a Sun JVM 1.6, it actually results in pretty uniform lease.

Anyways, I also tried to "bias" the leasing of semaphore with the strategy I wrote in my other answer. Turns out a simple extra `yield` statement alone results in significant bias. Your problem is more complicated, but perhaps you can do similar tests with your idea and see what you get :)

**NOTE** The code below is based upon Ceki's code [here](http://ceki.blogspot.com/2009/06/biased-locking-in-java-se-60.html)

Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class BiasedSemaphore implements Runnable {
    static ThreadLocal<Boolean> favored = new ThreadLocal<Boolean>(){
        private boolean gaveOut = false;
        public synchronized Boolean initialValue(){
            if(!gaveOut){
                System.out.println("Favored " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                gaveOut = true;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    static int THREAD_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    static Semaphore SEM = new Semaphore(1);
    static Runnable[] RUNNABLE_ARRAY = new Runnable[THREAD_COUNT];
    static Thread[] THREAD_ARRAY = new Thread[THREAD_COUNT];

    private int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        printEnvironmentInfo();
        execute();
        printResults();
    }

    public static void printEnvironmentInfo() {
        System.out.println("java.runtime.version = "
                + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
        System.out.println("java.vendor          = "
                + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
        System.out.println("java.version         = "
                + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("os.name              = "
                + System.getProperty("os.name"));
        System.out.println("os.version           = "
                + System.getProperty("os.version"));
    }

    public static void execute() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
            RUNNABLE_ARRAY[i] = new BiasedSemaphore();
            THREAD_ARRAY[i] = new Thread(RUNNABLE_ARRAY[i]);
            System.out.println("Runnable at "+i + " operated with "+THREAD_ARRAY[i]);
        }

        for (Thread t : THREAD_ARRAY) {
            t.start();
        }
        // let the threads run for a while
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        for (int i = 0; i< THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
            THREAD_ARRAY[i].interrupt();
        }

        for (Thread t : THREAD_ARRAY) {
            t.join();
        }
    }

    public static void printResults() {
        System.out.println("Ran with " + THREAD_COUNT + " threads");
        for (int i = 0; i < RUNNABLE_ARRAY.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("runnable[" + i + "]: " + RUNNABLE_ARRAY[i]);
        }
    }


    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            if (favored.get()) {
                stuff();
            } else {
                Thread.yield();
//                try {
//                    Thread.sleep(1);
//                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
//                }
                stuff();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stuff() {
        if (SEM.tryAcquire()) {
            //favored.set(true);
            counter++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            SEM.release();
        } else {
            //favored.set(false);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "counter=" + counter;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
java.runtime.version = 1.6.0_21-b07
java.vendor          = Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.version         = 1.6.0_21
os.name              = Windows Vista
os.version           = 6.0
Runnable at 0 operated with Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
Runnable at 1 operated with Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
Favored Thread-0
Ran with 2 threads
runnable[0]: counter=503
runnable[1]: counter=425
```

Tried with 30 seconds instead of 10:

```
java.runtime.version = 1.6.0_21-b07
java.vendor          = Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.version         = 1.6.0_21
os.name              = Windows Vista
os.version           = 6.0
Runnable at 0 operated with Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
Runnable at 1 operated with Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
Favored Thread-1
Ran with 2 threads
runnable[0]: counter=1274
runnable[1]: counter=1496
```

**P.S.:** Looks like "hanging out" was a very bad idea. When I tried calling `SEM.tryAcquire(1,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` for favored threads and `SEM.tryAcquire()` for non-favored threads, non-favored threads got the permit almost 5 times more than the favored thread!

Also, I'd like to add that these results are only measured under 1 particular situation, so it's not clear how these measures behave in other situations.

Comment: `Semaphore.tryAquire()` without a timeout is a non-fair method, which skips the queue if there is a permit available. This is often a good thing if fairness is not an issue, because it avoids a context-switch.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that the simplest way to do this is not to try and combine Semaphores, but to build it from scratch on top of monitors. This is generally risky, but in this case, as there are no good building blocks in java.util.concurrent, it's the clearest way to do it.

Here's what i came up with:

```
public class SemaphoreWithMemory {

    private final Set<Integer> favouredIDs = new HashSet<Integer>();
    private final Object favouredLock = new Object();
    private final Object ordinaryLock = new Object();
    private boolean available = true;
    private int favouredWaiting = 0;

    /**
    Acquires the permit. Blocks until the permit is acquired.
    */
    public void acquire(int id) throws InterruptedException {
        Object lock;
        boolean favoured = false;

        synchronized (this) {
            // fast exit for uncontended lock
            if (available) {
                doAcquire(favoured, id);
                return;
            }
            favoured = favouredIDs.contains(id);
            if (favoured) {
                lock = favouredLock;
                ++favouredWaiting;
            }
            else {
                lock = ordinaryLock;
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (available) {
                    doAcquire(favoured, id);
                    return;
                }
            }
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
    }

    private void doAcquire(boolean favoured, int id) {
        available = false;
        if (favoured) --favouredWaiting;
        else favouredIDs.add(id);
    }

    /**
    Releases the permit.
    */
    public synchronized void release() {
        available = true;
        Object lock = (favouredWaiting > 0) ? favouredLock : ordinaryLock;
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

}
```